# FirebaseError: Expected type 'Tc', but it was: a custom Ac object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to access all documents from my firestore collection

```js
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  const db = getFirestore(app);


  async function getTodos() {
        try {
            const todoRef = collection(db, 'todos');
            let allTodos = await getDoc(todoRef);
            console.log(allTodos)

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
```

but it's throwing this err
`FirebaseError: Expected type 'Tc', but it was: a custom Ac object`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `getDoc()` method is used to get a single document and takes a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) as a parameter. Here `todoRef` is a [CollectionReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.collectionreference) and to fetch multiple documents you must use `getDocs()` instead:

```
const todoRef = collection(db, 'todos');
let allTodos = await getDocs(todoRef);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have used getDoc() method which helps to get one single document so just replace your getDoc() with getDocs()

Comment: This answer was already provided in a more detailed way.

Answer (score 3):

Get only one document:

```
import { doc, getDoc , getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities", "SF");
const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
```

Get multiple documents from a collection

```
import { doc, getDoc , getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const docRef = doc(db, "cities");
const docs = await getDocs(q);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error this week, and the issue was that I was importing from two different versions of the `firebase/firestore` package... One version in my application, and a different version in the data layer which was in a separate NPM module.

Building that NPM module properly so that `firebase/firestore` was a peer dependency got the `getDoc` and `collection` functions using the same version of Firestore, which resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

while I believe what @Dharmaraj wrote is accurate and correct, I encountered a very similar error, and if you're here for this error, read below:

> FirebaseError: Expected type 'dh', but it was: a custom DocumentReference object

In my case, I was able to resolve the error by upgrading my firebase version from "firebase": "^9.22.1", to "firebase": "^10.8.1  (by running this command: npm install --save firebase@latest).

So now I'm running Angular 17, Angular Fire 17, Ionic 7, Node 18, firebase 10, and  my Ionic info is:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 7.2.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@ionic/cli)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 6.7.5
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 17.2.2
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 17.2.2
   @angular/cli                  : 17.2.2
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 6.1.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI      : 5.7.0
   @capacitor/android : 5.7.0
   @capacitor/core    : 5.7.0
   @capacitor/ios     : 5.7.0

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.4
   native-run  : 2.0.1

System:

   NodeJS : v18.19.1 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm    : 10.2.4
   OS     : macOS Monterey
```