# Porting v8 to v9, where to look: Expected type 'Pa', but it was: a custom ba object

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm porting an application from Firebase 8 to 9, and I'm bumping into this generic runtime error that also has no stack trace.

I have no idea where to look. Can anyone point me in a direction that makes sense?

Note that my app is not doing any Firestore mutations (no setDoc, updateDoc, etc), because all mutations happen via cloud functions. For this reason. I have no clue what to do because the error makes me think I'm passing in the wrong data somewhere.

--- edit ---

I have narrowed it down to this:

```
const ref = doc(db, `__derived_user_names/${accountId}`);

this.derivedUserNames = new ObservableDocument<Record<string, string>>(ref);
```

The ref is constructed properly, but the error happens when it is passed to the ObservableDocument constructor. Without the ref argument, the object is instantiated without problems.

This object is from a library I created some time ago (and now kind of regret). Here is a link to the source in the Firebase 9 branch that is used to run the code:

https://github.com/0x80/firestore-mobx/blob/topic/0630-firebase-9/src/document.ts

The weird thing is, I have tests for the library that are running against an actual Firestore instance, and during testing, everything works fine.

--- more findings ---

This is getting weird. In my library, if I use the passed in ref from my app, the error occurs. If I recreate a ref with its path (using the linked test database) and use that instead, there is no error.

If I print the refs both look the same, like a "ba object"

```
const ref = doc(db, this.documentRef.path);
console.log("++documentRef", this.documentRef);
console.log("++recreated ref", ref);

this.onSnapshotUnsubscribeFn = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => this.handleSnapshot(snapshot), (err) => this.handleError(err));
```

I am starting to feel that there might be a clash between the firebase web and admin SDKs. My app codebase uses both (monorepo using yarn workspaces).

Comment: Can you share the code that throws this error? This error can also show up when you are reading data and not only updating. Have you tried commenting any part of code that resolve the issue or so?

Comment: It is a fairly complex and private codebase that I'm porting. Since I do not have a stack trace and no clue where to look I also do not know yet how to isolate and share any code. I was hoping someone could at least give me a pointer on what this means and what might be the cause.

Comment: That usually means you are passing wrong argument, like using `getDocs()` with a `DocumentReference` as in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69580302/13130697) so it's hard to tell without any code .

Comment: ObservableDocument lets you pass in both a document and collection type reference. The collection type is used so you can attach it to a document id after instantiation. There is only one place in the document code that calls getDoc(s) and I've added an assert there to make sure the ref is the correct type, but that's not it. I will comment out parts of the constructor to narrow it down...

Comment: I have narrowed it down to the onSnapshot call. However, I can't find anything wrong with the reference that is passed in. I have extended the document tests so that the onSnaphot call is used in the same way (as opposed to the onReady => getDoc flow) and my test runs fine.

If I print the ref in the app it says `ba {converter: null, _key: dt, type: 'document', firestore: Fa}`  so it seems correct that it's a "ba object" but how I can make it the expected Pa object is still a mystery to me.

Comment: This is getting weird. In my library, if I use the passed in ref from my app, the error occurs. If I use the passed in ref to recreate a ref (using the linked test database) and use that instead, there is no error.

If I print the ref objects both appear to be the same "ba object"
```
const ref = doc(db, this.documentRef.path);
console.log("++documentRef", this.documentRef);
console.log("++recreated ref", ref);

this.onSnapshotUnsubscribeFn = onSnapshot(ref, (snapshot) => this.handleSnapshot(snapshot), (err) => this.handleError(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily I could halt this v9 migration for a while. I now came back to it with upgraded dependencies and it seems like error reporting was improved in the meantime.

I now get an informative error message:

> FirebaseError: Expected first argument to collection() to be a CollectionReference, a DocumentReference or FirebaseFirestore

Not completely sure if this is the same error that caused the cryptic message earlier but it seems likely.